# Creating list of Class Objects

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a Python program that creates a Class that can hold information and perform operations with contact objects.  Basically it's like a mobile phone which you can enter data for Name, Address, Phone, Age, and Type (like Family, Work, Friends, etc.)  I am pretty new to Python and I'm not too familiar with classes...

I came up with something like

```
CONTACTS = open ("contacts.txt","r")

CONTACT_DATA = CONTACTS.read()

class Contacts(CONTACT_DATA):

      def __init__(CONTACT_DATA, Name= "Unavailable", Address= "Unavailable",   Phone="Unavailable", Age=0, Type=None ):
            CONTACT_DATA.Name = Name
            CONTACT_DATA.Address = Address
            CONTACT_DATA.Phone = Phone
            CONTACT_DATA.Age = Age
            CONTACT_DATA.Type = Type
```

but I'm pretty much stuck on how to assign the strings to the variables.  I know I'm suppose to use the "set" and "get" methods...

the contacts.txt file would look something like

```
3 
Albert Einstein
27 Technology Drive
25
555-555-1212
WORK
Sally Field
48 Friendly Street
22
555-555-8484
FRIEND
Marvin Gaye
191 Apple Mountain Road
30
555-555-2222
RELATIVE
```

3 is the number of contacts.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can subclass _an instance of `str`_. A base class should be a class... _IMHO_ you don't need classes at all for this.

Comment: I would recommend you play around just with using classes (how to create them, use them, etc.) by just having code that manually creates a "Contact" object. For example, `c = Contact(name='Name', address='Address')` and then print data back on the screen until you're comfortable with what you're doing with classes. Once you're comfortable here, then try to work the reading of a file back into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're working with might be doable, but more like this:

```
class Contact(object):
  def __init__(self, name, address, age, phone, ctype):
    self.name = name,
    self.address = address
    self.age = age
    self.phone = phone
    self.ctype = ctype

# Read off the first line of your data file.
fh = open('contacts.txt')
count = int(fh.readline())

Contacts = [Contact(*c) for c in [[next(fh) for i in range(5)] for j in range(count)]]
```

As noted, the final line does use some nested list comprehensions.  That is the equivalent of this:

```
Contacts = []
for j in range(count):
  fields = []
  for i in range(5):
    fields.append(next(fh))
  Contacts.append(Contact(*fields))
```

Comment: "pretty new to Python" - the last line consists of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: As a side note: there are better text formats like csv or json (both supported by the standard lib).